# can any body tell me how to get user_id from request_id

Tags: facebook

I need to fetch user info as user accept app request...
so i need to get userId from request_id that is generated when sending request

Thanks...

Comment: Accept App Request? or Allow Application?

Comment: i got by using $facebook->api('me/apprequests/');

Thanks for attention

Comment: @Urvish: excuse me, how do you get the api call /me/apprequests to work? In my case it return a json object with the data = ''

Answer (score 0):

If you have the request ID, you can use the graph API to get the recipient [user] id with:

https://graph.facebook.com/REQUEST_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

If you need to get a number of request_ids at once you can use:

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=REQUEST_ID1,REQUEST_ID2,REQUEST_IDS4&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN